# shift changes the length of the array so the last element is not going to be executed

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, for a array, if methods such as pop, shift is used, the length of array changes as well. In my JS code below, it never executes the third elements 'Ds3' in the array since after the notes.shift() is executed, the length of the array becomes 0 so it just jumps out of the for loop, I do not know how to change the code so it can actually execute the 'Ds3'.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

Code 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ['F2', 'As2','Ds3'];
    for(i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {

        $('#_' + notes.shift()).addClass('just_do_it');
        alert(notes.length);
    }

});
```

For code 2, I do not know why when I sort of make the one line code to two liner, the code does not work at all.  Thank you in advance.
code 2:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ['F2', 'As2','Ds3'];
    var count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        var note = notes.shift();
        $('#_' + note).addClass('just_do_it');
        count++;
        alert(notes.length);
    }

});
```

Comment: you're iterating an array while making changes to it,expect unexpected behavior.

Comment: whenever you are performing a shift then make sure your counter variable is not incremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to empty that array? If insist on it, try changing to a while loop.

```
var notes = ['F2', 'As2','Ds3'];
var count = 0;
while(notes.length > 0){
    var note = notes.shift();
    $('#_' + note).addClass('shown');
    count++;
    alert(notes.length);
}
```

If I may add, you're also incrementing the count as you loop through the array. Rather you can get the count immediately just by getting the length of the array like this `var count = notes.length`

Also since you mentioned `pop` and `shift` arrays methods, you should checkout other [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) such as `forEach`, `map` or `reduce`

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea why it works for :while loop" but does not work for "for loop". When I used while loop, it indeed shows me that the length of the array is 0 so it should get out of the while loop, but it still executes addClass for the thid time.

Comment: You don't want to execute `addClass` for 'Ds3'?

Comment: To me, even though using while loop, the code can only execute addClass twice because notes.shift() make the array length to 0 so it does not have the chance to execute the addClass the third time

Comment: I want to execute addClass for 'Ds3' and your code truly does, but I just don't see the reason why it does since there is no difference between your while loop and my for loop

Comment: Each step of your `forloop` does 2 things, it increases the index, and takes away the first item of your array. So at step #2, your index has changed from 0 to 1 but your array has also changed from `['F2', 'As2', 'Ds3']` to `['As2', 'Ds3']` so it skips `'As2'`

Answer (score 1):

Since shift() is indeed destructive you could simply use the index of that iteration in the loop and leave the array unaltered

```
for(i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        // switch from `notes.shift() to notes[i]
        $('#_' + notes[i]).addClass('just_do_it');
        count++;
        alert(notes.length);// length remains unchanged
}
```

Or using join() to create a selector for all and not use any loop

```
$('#_' + notes.join(',#_') ).addClass('just_do_it');
```

Comment: Thank you charlie.  I want to empty the array for purpose.  I will take a deep look for join.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
for (var count = notes.length; count > 0; count--) {
        $('#_' + notes.shift()).addClass('just_do_it');
}
```

or

```
while (notes.length > 0) {
      $('#_' + notes.shift()).addClass('just_do_it');
}
```